# Why getAttribute() not giving result in selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I was trying to scrap yellow pages Australia page. I searched for all the [Piazza Restaurants](https://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=Pizza+Restaurants&locationClue=Sydney+CBD%2C+NSW&lat=&lon=) in Australia. Now I want to fetch the email of every restaurant which is the value of data-email(an attribute of an anchor tag). Below is my code and I used getAttribute() on the anchor tag, but it is always giving me this error.
`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

This is my code

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=Pizza+Restaurants&locationClue=Sydney+CBD%2C+NSW&lat=&lon="
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/local/share/chromedriver")
driver.get(url)

pageSource=driver.page_source
bsObj=BeautifulSoup(pageSource,'lxml')

items=bsObj.find('div',{'class':'flow-layout outside-gap-large inside-gap inside-gap-large vertical'}).findAll('div',class_='cell in-area-cell find-show-more-trial middle-cell')

for item in items:
    print(item.find('a',class_='contact contact-main contact-email ').getAttribute("data-email"))
```

Comment: Full traceback please.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `find_all` and not `findAll`?

Comment: I used `find_all` too still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tag.getAttribute` does not exist - you want either `Tag[<attrname>]` (if you are sure the item has this attribute) or `Tag.get(<attrname>[,default=None])` if you're not.

Note that with most Python objects you would have got an AttributeError but beautifulsoup uses the `__getattr__` hook a lot and returns `None` instead of raising an AttributeError when it cannot dynamically resolve an attribute, which is rather confusing.

This being said, `item.find()` *can* return `None` so you should indeed *also* test the result of `item.find()` before calling `.get()` on it, ie:

```
tag = item.find('a', ...)
if tag:
    email = tag.get("data-email")
    if email:
        print(email)
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I just want to know why getAttribute() didn't work, I look upon StackOverflow and many people have used that?

Comment: You must be confusing with javascript DOM stuff - BeautifulSoup always used a dict-like API for tags attributes as far as I can remember (you can check the  years old v3 doc, it already worked that way).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this
https://github.com/n0str/beautifulsoup-none-catcher

So, it becomes

```
from maybe import Maybe

bsObj=BeautifulSoup(pageSource,'lxml')

items=Maybe(bsObj).find('div',{'class':'flow-layout outside-gap-large inside-gap inside-gap-large vertical'}).find_all('div', {'class': 'cell in-area-cell find-show-more-trial middle-cell'})

print('\n'.join(filter(lambda x: x, [Maybe(item).find('a', {'class': 'contact-email'}).get("data-email").resolve() for item in items.resolve()])))
```

Output

```
[..]@crust.com.au
[..]@madinitalia.com
<...>
[..]@ventuno.com.au
```

Just wrap `Maybe(soup)` and call `.resolve()` afterwards